# How to prevent 'Elements from collapsing' when 'Vertical Viewport' becomes smaller?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website layout as an exercise, using `Flexbox`. But elements collapse into each other when I put the website through responsive test.

Using `Flexbox`, I tried to build a responsive website, where it would self-adjust ratios when you play with the dimensions of the browser. The horizon test was a pass, but when I opened the inspect tools, the "vertical view port" became smaller and the blue `'Section'` and the fuchsia `'Footer'` all collapsed into each other, because the vertical aspect of the website is not working as expected.

I tried to change and play around with different size `units` such as `{%, em, vh, vw}` to get the elements to readjust their sizes in relation to each other, but it still collapses into each other when I

I uploaded the code: {`HTML` & `CSS`} to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/karanius/pen/pozKqwa) as well.

```css
:root{
    text-align: center;
}

body{
 background-color: gray;
 height: 100vh;
}

.container{
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.headerAndNav{
}

.header{
    background-color: navajowhite;
    border: 0.5em solid gray;
}

.nav{
    background-color: powderblue;
    border: 0.5em solid gray;
}

.sectionAndAside{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
}

.header{
    height: 8vh;
}

.nav{
    height: 8vh;
}

.middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* background-color: red; */
    border: 0.5em solid gray;
    height: 40vh;
}

.aside{
    background-color: powderblue;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.section{
    color:red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.article{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 10px;
}

h1{
    background-color: bisque;
}

h2{
    background-color:gold;
}

h3{
    background-color: khaki;
}

.hClass{
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 10vh;
    margin: 1em;
}

.p{
    background-color: lightcoral;
    height: 10vh;  
    margin: 1em;  
}

.footer{
    background-color: fuchsia;
    border: 0.5em solid gray;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='sectionAndAside'>
        <div class='header'>header</div>
        <div class='nav'> nav</div>
     </div>
    <div class='middle'>
        <div class='section'>section
           <div class='article'>article
              <div class='conta'>
                <div class='hClass'>
                        <h1>h1</h1>
                        <h2>h2</h2>
                        <h3>h3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class='p'>
                        <p>this is p</p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <aside class='aside'>aside</aside>
      </div>
      <div class='footer'>footer</div>
</div>
```

I was hoping to find a `way/solution/method-of-approach` and learn how to how to effectively control the layout of a website when I build them from scratch. This image here (bottom), is exactly what I am trying to replicate. I eventually did, but it was not responsive. Initially I had trouble with controlling `div` s positions, but `flexbox` helped me with that. The objective now is to learn how to get the vertical properties of the elements to behave as well as the horizontal ones.

[image]

Comment: Please, show us your code, we can't help you if you don't

Comment: Sorry about that. It must be showing now

Answer (score 0):

use property flex wrap :wrap; it helps in small screen.
https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox